# Need to replace only display cable or entire display?

Tags: dell-inspiron

I have a Dell n5110. On startup I hear 8 beeps, the monitor shows only black screen. I pressed the 'D' key and the monitor flashed in different colors.
It happened me this a couple of times ago but I managed somehow to make it work. Now it works only with external monitor.
I red some articles on web and understood that if the monitor shows colors (on pressing D) the display is fine, it is just the cable.
My question is: how can I be sure that the display is fine and I only need to replace the display cable?

Or is there any other fix or details I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Eight beeps means a display failure.

Since the external monitor works, you know it's not a fault with the video card.

When holding down the <kbd>D</kbd> key and Powering the notebook on gets
solid colors on the screen, this means that the LCD is good and the problem
is with the video cable.

But as even this method does not work any more, the problem can be anything
at all. Maybe a repair-man could do better.